# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str | How to do associative arrays in Python?

Tags: python

I am getting the following error in Python 3.8:

```
results['article'] = row[0]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My query:

```
    curb = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
    curb.execute("""
        SELECT
            article,
            url
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
            id = %s
            -- %s
        LIMIT 2
        """, (
        test_id,
        test_id
    )
    )
    results = curb.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        results['article'] = row[0]
        results['url'] = row[1]
```

I know there are similar questions on SO, however I could not figure out so far how to build an associative array in python that serves this use case.

My goal is to pass the article along with the yield statement, which is why I am trying to put it into kind of an associative array.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for result in self.results:
        if validators.url(result['url']):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=result['url'],
                callback=self.parse_item,
                meta={'article': result['article']}
            )
        else:
            print("Invalid URL ", format(result['url']))
```

Comment: Post the outputs of `print(curb.fetchall())`

Comment: “Associative arrays” are dicts (`{}`) in Python. `results` is not a dict, it’s a list (`[]`).

Comment: @flakes It returns '[ ]' which is strange as the SQL returns 2 results as expexted when I execute it on the DB. Maybe something is wrong with the parametized query? I added a second parameter as it does not work with just one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that `results` is an object that is designed to return 0 or more rows of the database.  You know (because you have `id = xxx`) that only one row will be returned.  It looks like you want something like:

```
for row in results:
    answer = dict(article=row[0], url=row[1])
    break
```

You may also want to initialize `answer` to `None` in case that no rows are returned.

---

Based on your comments below, it sounds like you want:

```
answer = {}
for row in result:
    article = row[0]
    url = row[1]
    answer[url] = article
```

which will give you a map from URL to article.  If you are comfortable with Python, that can be simplified to one line using dictionary comprehension:

```
answer = {row[1]: row[0] for row in result}
```

Comment: actually multiple rows will be returned, this is just a minimal example

Comment: Okay.  I was going to ask a different question, until I saw you were only returning a single row.  You have multiple pairs of articles and urls.  Say you have ten rows.  You'll have ten urls and their associated article.  What do you want your result to look like?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by single row. The result returns 2 rows (limit 2). Each row contains a URL and an article. My goal is to get thousands of rows where I know which article belongs to which URL

Comment: See additional comments in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you actually want:

```py
    curb = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
    curb.execute(
        # ...
    )
    # notice the names of variables
    fetch_results = curb.fetchall()
    results = []
    for row in fetch_results:
        result = {}
        result['article'] = row[0]
        result['url'] = row[1]
        # collect other information of this row...
        results.append(result)
```